# Spring creating collection in view

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, view, converters

[image: View]

Let's say our view gets a list of all the "Ingrediënt" in our DB, we now want to add the Quantity info to each Ingrediënt.

### Logic:

**IngredientQuantity:**

- Ingrediënt : ingredient
- Quantity : quantity

**Quantity:**

- String : unit
- int : quantity

**Ingrediënt:**

- String : name

**Dish:**

- Collection : ingredients
- String : name

### Question:

How can we combine the input of each Selected Ingrediënt to a list of IngredientQuantity. We only want our list to contain the Selected Ingredients.

*Notes.*
A `Quantity` has a `String unit` and a `Int quantity` field

*Extra.*
I was thinking to use a custom Converter, but wouldn't have a clue on how to do it.

Comment: does Ingrediënt has a IngredientQuantity field? Please share the whatever JSP snippet you have now.

Comment: Don't really have anything yet, still in the thinking phase :)

Comment: hahaha... You don't need a converter. does Ingrediënt has a IngredientQuantity field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need a `Converter`. Converter is used to for advanced type conversion like converting an incoming string *'yyyy-mm-dd zone'* to `java.util.Date` and vice versa.

Spring provides [JSTL tags library](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/view.html#view-jsp-formtaglib) to attach modelAttribute to a `<form>` and its field.

You can also attach a list of IngredientQuantity to the `<form>` and there are many tutorials on how to use list inside `<form>`.

One such example is [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-multi-row-submit-java-list/)

**UPDATE:**

In your case, you will add Dish and an empty list of IngredientQuantity to the model in your controller setup method as below

```
class IngredientFormModel{

   //It is important to use AutoPopulatingList as your list is dynamic 
   AutoPopulatingList<IngredientQuantity> ingredientQuantityList = new AutoPopulatingList<IngredientQuantity>(IngredientQuantity.class);   
}

@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String setupForm(Model model) {      
    model.addAttribute("dish", dish);

    IngredientFormModel ingredientFormModel = new IngredientFormModel();

    model.addAttribute("ingredientFormModel", ingredientFormModel)
    return "viewName";
}
```

Attach your ingredientFormModel to the `<form>` and use `.` operator to access nested fields
(Note: You can access dish in JSP as a regular attribute in requestScope)

```
<form:form modelAttribute="ingredientFormModel">
    Dish Name: ${dish.name} <br>
    <c:forEach var="ingredient" items="${dish.ingredients}" varStatus="count">
        Ingredient Name: ${ingredient.name} <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="ingredientFormModel.ingredientQuantityList[${count.index}].name" value="${ingredient.name}" />
        Quantity: <input name="ingredientFormModel.ingredientQuantityList[${count.index}].quantity.quantity" type="text" /> </br>
        Unit: <input name="ingredientFormModel.ingredientQuantityList[${count.index}].quantity.unit" type="text"/> </br>
    </c:forEach>         
</form:form>
```

In your controller class, you can retrieve the object as below

```
@ModelAttribute("ingredientFormModel") IngredientFormModel ingredientFormModel
```

Comment: So for me, IngredientQuantity would be similar to Contact and Dish would be similar to ContactForm. But how will Spring know which fields are used as Quantity, etc ? Cause i set the <form:form modelAttribute on Dish. So i'd think that Spring will look for a setUnit(...)/setQuantity(...) method in the Dish class (which doesn't existe there) ?

Comment: No. you will attach the bean for which you want input from user. In your case it will be ingredientQuantityList and not dish. You can access nested elements using `.` operator. I have updated my answer with relevant details.

Comment: okay, it is getting more clear, but i dont quite understand what the "ProductModel" clas does ?

Comment: I think your IngredientQuantity class should have ingredient name/id but not Ingredient object itself.

Comment: Ohh that's my bad. ProductModel is my example class. Missed to update it. Please check again.

Comment: i was also wondering, `<form:hidden path="ingredientQuantityList[${count.index}].name" />` dont you have to pass a vlaue to this hidden field ?

Comment: you used ProductModel in the AutoPopulatingList

Comment: kindly note that in the link you provided me they tell us that Sping mvc 3.0 removes the "[]" brackets from your form:input fields, so you have to use the old <input ... /> tags.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54648/discussion-between-javakid-and-mrme-tumbsup).

Comment: i'm wondering, the submission gets sent to my controller. how do i then get this list ?
protected modelAndView submission(@RequestAttribute ???type??? ingredientQuantityList){}
what type ?
again AutoPopulatedList ?

Comment: `@ModelAttribute("ingredientQuantityList") AutoPopulatedList ingredientQuantityList`. Beware when you iterate the list there may be some null values. For example, if the user selects ingredients 1 & 3, the length of the list will be 3 but value at 2 will be null. So check for null as you retrieve values from the list

Comment: I cannot retrieve any AutopopulatedList object : `[Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.util.AutoPopulatingList]: No default constructor found; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.util.AutoPopulatingList.<init>()] with root cause
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.util.AutoPopulatingList.<init>()`

Comment: I think this is due to the fact that you pass the class type in the constructor of an AutoPopulatedList. `new AutotPopulatedList<type>(type.class);` ?

Comment: Sorry, I just realized that AutopopulatedList can't be declared directly on the controller. What we need is a wrapper model. I updated the answer. Please check.

Comment: for some reason this isn't adding the input data into the list, i keep on getting a list with size=0

Comment: do you have setter and getter methods for the list in the model? Can you please paste the generated HTML for one field? It should work if everything is done correctly.

Comment: shall we continue in chat ?

Comment: [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/54648/discussion-between-javakid-and-mrme-tumbsup)